# Firebase with Phonegap - works perfect on index.html page while working partially on other pages

Tags: cordova, firebase

I've start playing a bit with Firebase and Phonegap (currently only for Android, using the online build tool from Adobe). I took the Firebase chat sample from their site and rather pasted it almost 'as is' to an index.html page, bundled with the required by phonegap config.xml.
When running the app with single index.html on my android mobile - it runs 100%.
when I move it to some internal page (i.e. chat.html), linked to index.html, I can receive incoming chats but none are going out. Looks like something is not loading correctly even though the same code works when it appears on index.html.

My guess is that it somehow related to the references  I stated, their order and location.

Here are snippets from my code, I can state some more if needed:

on config.xml:

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/notification"/>
<access origin="*" />
```

on index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="firebase.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="my.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

on chat.html I commented all the script tags (and of course tried also with all of them exist (uncommented) with same results).

my.js (complete):

```
    $(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
    // Make your jQuery Mobile framework configuration changes here!

    $.support.cors = true;
    $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    // Get a reference to the root of the chat data.
    var messagesRef = new Firebase('https://alon.firebaseio.com/');

    $('.send-action').click(function () {
        var name;
        if (navigator.platform == 'Win32') {
            name = 'me';
        } else {
            name = device.name + ' (' + device.uuid + ')'; //$('#nameInput').val();
        }
        var text = $('#messageInput').val();
        messagesRef.push({ name: name, text: text });
        $('#messageInput').val('');
    });

    // Add a callback that is triggered for each chat message.
    messagesRef.on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
        var message = snapshot.val();
        $('<div/>').text(message.text).prepend($('<em/>').text(message.name + ': ')).appendTo($('#messagesDiv'));
        $('#messagesDiv')[0].scrollTop = $('#messagesDiv')[0].scrollHeight;
        if (message.name != device.name + ' (' + device.uuid + ')') {
            navigator.notification.beep(1);
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: I thank everyone who read this one but I have decided to move all my pages to the single index.html file.
jQuery supports automatically hiding/showing <page> tags so its rather easy.
And the above works (as mentioned above, it worked already when was on the first page).

Answer (score 1):

Are you listening for the deviceready event? You need to on any page that makes use of PhoneGap Device APIs. I see you are using JQM which means your pages will *normally* load via AJAX, making my suggestion invalid, but if you overrode that (JQM lets you do that) then this would be a problem.

Comment: No, I'm not. the only js I'm using is mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a little late and you've likely realized it already-- but the reason the firebase stopped working when you moved all that code to another page is that likely the page you moved it to was outside of the root folder (ie- /chat/index.html).

You have two script references above where the sources are "firebase.js" and "my.js".  These are "relative URLs" which means they are relative to where the document containing these files is located.  So-- if you put this code as-is on a page at the URL /chat/index.html your references to those two js files are really looking for "http://yourdomain.com/chat/firebase.js" and "http://yourdomain.com/chat/my.js"... but if you didn't copy those files to the /chat/ directory they'll come up as a 404 error (or not found) and the script won't work.  The correct way to fix this for both instances is to use an "absolute URL" instead.  By adding a "/" to each script reference, you'll make it absolute so instead of "my.js" make it "/my.js" because the browser sees this as an absolute URL, inferring the "/" as the root of your domain.

Comment: Hi thetrickster, yes, it is a bit too late as I moved all to a single page which works. And no, all html files were in the root folder (all of that was only a small POC). Thanks anyway.